# Is it safe to use "reboot" in rcS init script?

Tags: init, reboot, busybox

We are using busybox and embedded Linux on arm A7. We need reboot opeartion in rcS init script(such as in `/etc/rcS.d/S02mountall.sh`) in some cases. I wonder if I can use busybox command "`reboot`" in `S02mountall.sh` directly? Is it safe?

Thanks,
Yan